# Casting an object to a type that may add more properties over time

Tags: typescript

In my app I'm getting a result object from aws and then for Typescript to be happy and to allow autocomplete and type checking I have to cast that as an specific type.

So I have this code:

```
var results = await getFromAWS(getItem); // or an existing object type
var cdnObject = getCDNObject(results);
```

And these methods:

```
export type CDNObject = {
   url: string;
}
export function getCDNObject(value = null): CDNObject {

   if (value) return value;

   return {
      url: ""
   }
}
```

But what happens if aws changes the result object or more specifically adds more properties than I have defined on my type?

If I understand it's just satisfies the compiler and an object with more properties just has more properties?

**More Info:**

Also, this function returns an empty object of the return type:

```
var cdnObject = getCDNObject();
```

Again, this is for type checking, auto complete and so on. There is no `new` keyword for types (afaik).

```
var cdnObject = new CDNObject();  // throws an error
```

Adding a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgIgOQPICMBWEDGwoF4oDeAsAFBTkCuATgDYBcUAzsFQJYB2A5gNykC%20pUgDMK7bKwD27KJwjB4ydFmAAKAG4BDGhQgMN7EHijsKNGgEoGC1BmyFBZcqyFR1WneahU51aZu0QvCSk5F4%20VNLEjqFQ1PRQAEQJIeQCJGnCouJSMnJwGsAaKp5Rod7AvoR8QRkkmlRQEkrYAGJUEgC2ACoAFhAAyhBUakNGssD5hcVBpPVQmAAm7DbKY3LWzapNtsBtnb0DQyNU5txQQA) for the example in the browser.

Comment: ① Adding more properties doesn't hurt anything in TypeScript; I'm not sure if it matters to whatever systems you're interacting with. ②  You're not "casting" anywhere in this code that I can see; what do you mean by "casting"? ​③ There should be a single question per post, so the "also related" part should be removed or promoted to the primary question.  ④ Please consider [edit]ing the code to be a [mre] we can paste into our own IDEs to see what you're talking about, without undeclared types/values or unrelated problems (like the fact that `value` can only be `null` in your code).

Comment: @jcalz I added more details. getCDNObject() will return a new object of the type and if a value is passed in it returns the object with the return type implied

Comment: "In Typescript there is no `as` keyword"  [Yes there is.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).  I understand your question less than I did before your update.  What can we do here?

Comment: While it's great that you've got the information you need, the question should be improved for the sake of future readers. The section about `as` is incorrect and distracting. And the code isn't a [mre]; please: declare `getFromAWS()`; change the call signature of `getCDNObject()` so that the `value` parameter can be non-`null`; fix `var person = (object): Person { return object };` to something syntactically valid. Ideally any TS code you post should only have the issues you're asking about; maybe test in an IDE? I'd [edit] for you but I'm pretty confused about what your code is doing.

Comment: @jcalz the call getCDNObject() can be non null. if you call getCDNObject() it will return an empty object. if you pass an object to getCDNObject(myObject) it simply returns it

Comment: @jcalz I think that `as` will work. I don't know why I didn't use it in the past. I used the method above to get past some typescript error I now wish I had posted as a question.

Comment: The argument to `getCDNObject()` must either be `null` or `undefined` according to your example code.  [Look, here's a demonstration in an IDE](https://tsplay.dev/w299xW).  If you don't mean for that to be the case, then you should change its call signature.   I must be failing to communicate properly because everything I can think of to say I've already said multiple times.  I'm going to disengage now; good luck!

Comment: @jcalz if you pass in an object to getCDNObject(value) it will simply be returned (and typescript compiler will be happy). If you pass nothing in to getCDNObject() then an object is created and it is returned. It servers two purposes. One to let the compiler know what type of object is returned by the function and two, to return an empty instance of an object informing the compiler again of the type.

Comment: I see Typescript is throwing an error in the browser. In my case it's not. But I added a type to the parameter and the error goes away. I'll add the code. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgIgOQPICMBWEDGwoF4oDeAsAFBTkCuATgDYBcUAzsFQJYB2A5gNykC+pUgDMK7bKwD27KJwjB4ydFmAAKAG4BDGhQgMN7EHijsKNGgEoGC1BmyFBZcqyFR1WneahU51aZu0QvCSk5F4+VNLEjqFQ1PRQAEQJIeQCJGnCouJSMnJwGsAaKp5Rod7AvoR8QRkkmlRQEkrYAGJUEgC2ACoAFhAAyhBUakNGssD5hcVBpPVQmAAm7DbKY3LWzapNtsBtnb0DQyNU5txQQA